# Android create an array of color in xml color

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, colors

Hi i want to create a viewpager so i follow this tutorial : https://blog.mindorks.com/android-viewpager-in-kotlin. But when i try to set up the array of color in res.colors :

```
<array name=”bg_color”>
        <item name=”bg_screen1">#f64c73</item>
        <item name=”bg_screen2">#20d2bb</item>
        <item name=”bg_screen3">#3395ff</item>
        <item name=”bg_screen4">#c873f4</item>
    </array>
```

This doesn't compile, i got Attribute value expected on = of the first line. And i got type attribute should be define on all other lines. I assume that i should define a type of the array, but which type should i use for colors? and how to declare it ?

**EDIT**

To use it you have to declare and IntArray then select the good position :

```
val bg_color = resources.getIntArray(R.array.bg_color)
webView.setBackgroundColor(bg_color[pos])
```

Exemple for a web view where pos is an int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think you copy paste code from that tutorial and because of that issue happens for **" "** . 
>   Please add below code .

```
<array name="bg_color">
    <item name="bg_screen1">#f64c73</item>
    <item name="bg_screen2">#20d2bb</item>
    <item name="bg_screen3">#3395ff</item>
    <item name="bg_screen4">#c873f4</item>
</array>
```

Comment: Ok you right it's seem that the copy from the tutorial made the error. Thanks you fixed it

Answer (score 3):

Don't give a name to each row, it's an `array`, not a `map`:

```
 <string-array name=”bg_color”>
            <item>#f64c73</item>
            <item>#20d2bb</item>
            <item>#3395ff</item>
            <item>#c873f4</item>
        </string-array>
```

Comment: And how can i acces it afterward?

Comment: `String[] colors = getResources.getStringArray(R.array.bg_color);`